# Nested for Loop optimization in python

Tags: python, loops, optimization

i want to optimize 2 for loops into single for loop, is there any way as length of array is very large.

```
A = [1,4,2 6,9,10,80] #length of list is very large
B  = []
for x in A:
    for y in A:
        if x != y:
            B.append(abs(x-y))
print(B)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Is that really the way you want your code to run? The output of that snippet is ok?

Comment: What is that between the second and third comma in `A`: the numbers `2` and `6` or the number `26`? As it is now, your code will stop with a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

not any better but more pythonic:

```
B = [abs(x-y) for x in A for y in A if x!=y]
```

unless you absolutely need duplicates (`abs(a-b) == abs(b-a)`), you can half your list (and thus computation):

```
B = [abs(A[i]-A[j]) for i in range(len(A)) for j in range(i+1, len(A))]
```

finaly you can use the power of `numpy` to get C++ speedup:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array(A)
A.shape = -1,1 # make it a column vector

diff = np.abs(A - A.T) # diff is the matrix of abs differences

# grab upper triangle of order 1 (i.e. less the diagonal)
B = diff[np.triu_indices(len(A), k=1)]
```

But this will always be O(n^2) no matter what...